# Implementing a model in Keras. How to interpret padding/stride values?

Tags: keras, tf.keras

I am trying to implement the model from the image.

[image]

Everything is clear beside the stride/padding notation.

I do not know how to interpret/code a Stride/Padding from for example 1/2 in Keras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly pass the stride argument to the keras Layer. stride of `(1,1)` is equivalent to no stride. A padding of (2,2) for a kernel of size 5x5 means that the output image has the same dimension than the input one. The Keras way is asking for padding = `"same"`

The stride is how many pixels to skip in horizontal and vertical direction when applying the convolution kernel in the input image.

The padding is how border images pixels shall be replicated (if needed) to keep the original input dimension when filtering through 2D convolution. A 3x3 kernel will miss pixels around the centering kernel one when applied on images border. Adding padding ensure the missing pixels are created from existing ones (by replicating border pixels values). If not the kernel is not applied to border pixels and hence the dimension of the output images are reduced (1 pixel lost for each border for a 3x3 kernel, 2 pixels for a 5x5)
eg:

```
conv1 = Conv2D(20, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding = 'same',strides = (1,1))
```